# Can't get an interactive Docker shell inside screen

Tags: docker, gnu-screen

I can't get an interactive shell to my Docker container inside a screen session. Outside from screen everything works fine. After starting the container is working in background and is not attachable at all.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the `-t -i` options while launching your container ?

Answer (score 2):

If your container is running and you're using a relatively up-to-date version of Docker (I can't remember the version number when this was added), you can do the following to get shell access to the container:

```
docker exec -it my_container_name_or_hash bash
```